# Sass - How to use a variable inside another variable

Tags: variables, sass

I have these 3 colors defined:

```
$brancheColor-firstbranche: red;
$brancheColor-secondbranche: blue;
$brancheColor-thirdbranche: green;
```

Then I'm creating a foreach loop with a certain branche name:

```
$totalBranches: (firstbranche, secondbranche, thirdbranche);
```

Which I iterate trough using a Sass `@each` loop:

```
@each $branche in $totalBranches {

   body##{$branche} {
     // After the "-" sign, where it says #{$branche} should be the var
     background-color:$brancheColor-#{$branche};
   }

}
```

So I want to use a predefined custom variable, in a variable. Is this possible?

---

**Edit: Added a picture of my code.**

The blue indication is where the magic should happen. The name "marketing" which stands behind $brancheColor-marketing should change in this case.

[image: code example]

Comment: Not quite I think, the example you provided uses numbers to iterate trough the list. But in my case, can I use a counter of some sort in my each loop?

Comment: Oh snap, I was overthinking it. I got it now. I ended up combining the first for loop with 2 variables in it. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is interested, combine the 2 var's in a list. One you can call with nth child 1, the other with nth 2.

[image: Solution]